# Ant Design Conditionally Require Form.Item

Tags: reactjs, antd

How to conditionally require a Form.Item in Ant design?

```
rules={[
   {
       required: {this.state.isRequired},
       message: 'This field is required',
   },
]}
```

Doesn't work with a variable as the value

I can use

```
<Form.Item>
 required={this.state.isRequired}
</Form.Item>
```

To get the star to show up, indicating it is required, but doesn't actually prevent a user from submitting without a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error on `required: {this.state.isRequired}`, remove curly braces from your state value should be working

```
rules={[
   {
       required: this.state.isRequired,
       message: 'This field is required',
   },
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove curly braces from `required: {this.state.isRequired}`

**You** can also use ternary operator in order to apply conditional required.

example:

```js
let condition = true

rules={[
   {
       condition ? this.state.isRequired: null,
       message: 'This field is required',
   },
]}
```